# Date-picker in android studio by clicking button

Tags: android

I set a date picker in a editText and it will work by clicking a button, so I set a onClick method setDate and code

```
public void setDate(View v){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthofyear, int dayofmonth) {
                e5.setText(dayofmonth + "-" + monthofyear + "-" + year);
            }
        },day,month,year);
        dpd.show();
    }
```

but it willn't work. What's the problem of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
public void setDate(View v) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthofyear, int dayofmonth) {
            e5.setText(dayofmonth + "-" + monthofyear + "-" + year);
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    dpd.show();
}
```

Exchange the positions of `day` and  `year`.
Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    textfield.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view == dob) {
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    Date d = sdf.parse("31/12/2000");

                    fromDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(d.getTime());
                    fromDatePickerDialog.show();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


           }
        }
    });

    final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {



        public  void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            textfield.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));

        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```